# Connection string without error page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gridview and sqldatasource like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [string]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" 
            ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HOSTNAME" HeaderText="HOSTNAME" 
            SortExpression="HOSTNAME" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE" HeaderText="DATE" SortExpression="DATE" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="INT" HeaderText="INT" SortExpression="INT" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

But when connection getting error, page getting error too.

I want to use this connection without error page. If connection have any problem(not connect, table does not exist etc.), page must open without error.

I can do it with try/catch with oledbconnection at code behind. How can I do that for sqldatasource?

ConnectionString:

```
<add name="dbConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=databaseip:1521/orcl;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=pass;Unicode=True" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

Comment: It is not good practice to have your datasource neither in your page nor in its code behind.You'd better use a data access layer to make the data access operations transparent to your UI layer.

Comment: Using datasource in code behind will be so much easier and will give you better way to debug it

Comment: Can you show some example for this?

Comment: There isn't a way to not get the page to display with an error. you need to move the logic/DAL code to codebehind and handle your errors there and then let the page still serve.

Comment: @Ric It will : http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment here is a basic example you can expand from this as required.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Your Connection String"))
{
  string sqlQuery = "Your Query";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, connection))
    {
      using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
      {
          connection.Open();
          sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
          DataTable dt = new DataTable();
          sda.Fill(dt);
          GridView1.DataSource = dt;
          GridView1.DataBind();
       }
    }
}
```

The code makes use of the `using` block so the object will get disposed correctly. I would also recommend you have a separate function which returns a `DataTable` and then in the `Page_Load`do

```
GridView1.DataSource = FunctionName;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thank you. It's getting error `Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0`.

Comment: It's got to do with your `connectionstring` make sure you call it in your code `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionStringName"].ConnectionString;`

Comment: Edited my question, added connectionstring. Try to connect OracleDatabase from OracleClient. I use sqldatasource because I don't have `Oracle.DataAccess`. Thats why it's getting error? I tried your call, getting error: `a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server`

Comment: Forcedly, I use oledb for your code. Changed sqlconnection to oledbconnection and it's working for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

Add  `using System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection;` to the top of your file, and remove the `using System.Data.SqlConnection;`

In web.config add this to your provider name

`providerName="System.Data.OleDb"`

if you dont want `oledb` change your providername

`providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Comment: Getting error: `Keyword not supported: 'provider'.`

Comment: I don't want to use oledb, I want to use sqlconnection.

Comment: please show me your `web.config` connection string.

Comment: if you don't want `oledb` then change your providerName to `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"` and try.